# Azure Connect won't connect

Tags: azure, azure-connect

Just installed azure connect on my localhost, but it won't connect. I see my machine dbates-HP as a active endpoint in my vistual network/connect section on my azure portal  and organized it into a group.

I can see in the azure connect portal that the machine endpoint is active, and that it refreshes since the last connected updates.

My local connect client lists the following diagnostics messages:

> Policy Check: There is no connectivity policy on this machine.
> IPsec certificate check: No IPsec certificate was found.

Also, I tried with firewall turned off.

Answer (score 0):

In some scenarios getting Windows Azure connect to working becomes very complex. I have worked on multiple such scenarios and found most common issues are related with network settings. To start investigate you need to collect the Azure Connect logs first from your machine and try to figure the problem out by yourself. I have described some info about collecting log here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/05/17/collecting-diagnostics-information-for-windows-azure-connect-related-issues.aspx

To open a free Windows Azure support incident please use link below:
https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=14928&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn

Answer (score 0):

Have you "linked" your Azure role with the machine group you created? The message "There is no connectivity policy on this machine" suggests that you haven't defined (in portal) to whom this machine should connect to.